# The convergence of constant sequence in topology

Tags: general-topology

Let  be any set and let  ∈ . Let $T_p$ = {⊆: =   ∉ } . Is this topology $_1$, $_2$  or  $_0$? And Investigate the convergence of constant sequences. That is sequences of the form {$x_n$} where $x_n$ = x for all n.

I can prove that this topology is $T_0$. But I do not know how to do convergence part. Please help. Thanks

Comment: What have you done so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Hmmm … looking at your notation, I'd say that $T_p$ is $T_1$ if $p=1$, and so on. I'm sure that's not what you meant. You might consider naming the topology differently.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: First prove (if you’ve not already done so) that if $x_n=x$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$, then the sequence  $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $x$ no matter what the topology on $X$ is. Then you can get to what I suspect is the intended point of the problem. Show that if $x\ne p$, the sequence actually converges to **two different** points of $X$. You can do this by actually finding the other point to which it converges and showing that it really does converge to that point as well as to $x$.

Comment: Please give me more detail since I am a new with topology. Thanks

Comment: @VuiTinh: You can show that *every* sequence in this space converges to $p$.